# WebLogic notification for c# (SNMP)

Tags: c#, weblogic, alert, snmp, pooling

I'm on a small c# project that must include Weblogic status in real time!

I've seen that Weblogic could use SNMP for diagnostics... unfortunately I’ve never used SNMP.

So with that protocol is it possible to be alerted by Weblogic of alerts and notification (Fe: deployment finished)? And it is possible to do it as a listener and not pooling Weblogic...

If it's not possible do you have any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic SNMP management guide can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13743/toc.htm. There are traps/notiifcations defined for WebLogic shutdowns and restarts, but not for application deployments. It looks like you can pull the application state from the WebLogic MIB.